# loop (iterate) flush-lines on a list of regex for large files

Tags: regular-expressions

I have a file (a log) with unique identifiers.  I know I can exclude a single unique identifier in emacs using M-x flush-lines.  I sometimes need to exclude more than one unique identifier, and for up to ten or twenty this is not a problem as I can do it by hand. This is usually sufficient for my needs.  However, there is the occasional need to exclude significantly more. Today, for instance, I need to exclude some 80k instances of unique identifiers (out of a file that might have over 300k unique ids. (I'm trying to locate the proverbial needle in a haystack and have a way to identify one kind of 'not needle' that is present 'and now I need a way to get them out of the way quickly)

Is there a way to loop through flush-lines over a list of regex? (and when I say 'loop', I'm purely being descriptive: I don't, necessarily, mean the function loop.  I'm given to understand 'while' and 'dolist' are similar functions... I don't know how to use any of them in this case)

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean you want to run `flush-lines` 80K times, each time with a different regexp? This might be easier to do from the command line via `grep -v`.

Comment: Yes, Tyler, that's essentially what I mean.  I thought of the grep -v (egrep, actually) option but each instance of exclusion leaves me with a file that thats got the remaining 79,999 regex 's and I have to, it seems to me, iterate on the file creation.   Much simpler, I would think, to let emacs buffer manage to do it...  But, as you may have gueessed, I'm not a programmer...

Comment: This might get you started: https://gist.github.com/plantarum/80937e21cde1f51764ee3727f92a50a6

Comment: Certainly you can do what you want. Obtain a list of the identifiers (from reading a file or whatever), then use `dolist` over the list, calling `flush-lines` for each (from `point-min` each time). This is just as easy and performant as combining them into a single regexp `\(foo\|bar\|...\)` and using a single invocation of `flush-lines`. (And such a large combination regexp might lead to regexp overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

You might like to read those 80K identifiers, then combine them into a single regexp with `regexp-opt` and then pass that to a single `flush-lines` call.  This said, maybe it'll fail because the resulting regexp is too large (Emacs has a limit on the size of its regexps).

Comment: Note that regexp-opt takes literal strings, not regexps. If you include e.g. an anchor in your regexps you'll have to factor it out.